# How to scroll to next div with full page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

when it's clicked to smoothly scroll to next div
and Divs that take 100% height
but
I want to scroll to the next div instead of the "next" button
who can help me to edit this code?
pleas help guys to make my web site

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".p2").offset().top
    },
    'slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.p1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.p2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #E91E63;
}

.p3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #01579B;
}

.admin {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p1">
</div>
<div class="p2">
</div>
<div class="p3">
</div>
<div class="admin">
  <button class="next">NEXT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. When running your snippet, the Next button scrolls smoothly down to p2, which is exactly what the code you've written says it should do. Did you want the first click to scroll to p2, and a second click to scroll to p3?

Comment: You misunderstand them @BrettDonald, they mean each scroll will scroll down once section at a time (like when click the button) instead of normal behavior now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think CSS's Scroll Snap feature can help you;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts
https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-snap

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".p2").offset().top
    },
    'slow');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

div[class*=p] {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.p1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.p2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #E91E63;
}

.p3 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #01579B;
}

.admin {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="p1">
  </div>
  <div class="p2">
  </div>
  <div class="p3">
  </div>
  <div class="admin">
    <button class="next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
</div>
```